# Reshape data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The dataset looks like this:-

```
Source      Jan_values   Feb_values    Mar_values
ABC          100           200          300
XYZ          200           300          400
```

i want to reshape the dataset which should look like this:

```
Source     Month     values
ABC         Jan      100
ABC         Feb      200
ABC         Mar      300
XYZ         Jan      200
XYZ         Feb      300
XYZ         Mar      400


df = df.stack()
```

Comment: Try: `pd.melt(df, id_vars='Source', value_vars=['Jan_values', 'Feb_values', 'Mar_values'])`

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.melt` and sort the values by column `source` and `Month` columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source':['ABC','XYZ'], 'Jan_values':[100,200], 'Feb_values':[200,300], 'Mar_values':[300,400]})

df.columns = [c.replace("_values","") for c in df.columns]

df = df.melt(id_vars=['source'], var_name='Month')

# to sort by month namea
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
          "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], categories=months, ordered=True)

print(df.sort_values(by=['source','Month']))
```

Output:

```
   source Month  value                                                                                                                          
2    ABC   Jan    100                                                                                                                          
0    ABC   Feb    200                                                                                                                          
4    ABC   Mar    300                                                                                                                          
3    XYZ   Jan    200                                                                                                                          
1    XYZ   Feb    300                                                                                                                          
5    XYZ   Mar    400
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for pandas **0.24+** - sorting is not necessary:

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) if first column `Source` is not index, then remove `_values` from columns names and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last set new index names and use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print (df)
    Source  Jan_values  Feb_values  Mar_values  Apr_values
0    ABC         100         200         300         455
1    XYZ         200         300         400         467

df1 = (df.set_index('Source')
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_values',''))
         .stack()
         .rename_axis(['Source','Month'])
         .reset_index(name='values'))
print (df1)
  Source Month  values
0    ABC   Jan     100
1    ABC   Feb     200
2    ABC   Mar     300
3    ABC   Apr     455
4    XYZ   Jan     200
5    XYZ   Feb     300
6    XYZ   Mar     400
7    XYZ   Apr     467
```

Solution for old pandas versions - use ordered [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html), because default sorting in function `stack`:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
          "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

df = df.set_index('Source').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_values',''))

df.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns, categories=months, ordered=True)

df1 = df.stack().rename_axis(['Source','Month']).reset_index(name='values')
print (df1)
  Source Month  values
0    ABC   Jan     100
1    ABC   Feb     200
2    ABC   Mar     300
3    ABC   Apr     455
4    XYZ   Jan     200
5    XYZ   Feb     300
6    XYZ   Mar     400
7    XYZ   Apr     467
```

Comment: @anky_91 - It depends, obviously is no reason avoid `Categorical`s, but if really need strings for some reason is possible cast to strings.